# Laravel Routes::When no longer works. What would be the alternative?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Context, I'm bumping an old version of laravel into a newer version.

I have been able to fix several leaky holes, however, there is one, in particular, that is getting hard to find a solution for and that is this:

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'isAdmin');
```

It seems like the ::when thing no longer works.

Keep in mind I'm not a PHP developer, hell this is actually the first time I'm using PHP at all.

Here's the routing page (web.php)).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\User;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::resource('admin/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', array('only' => array('index')));
Route::resource('admin/companies', 'App\Http\Controllers\CompaniesController');
Route::resource('admin/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController');

Route::resource('admin/public_polls', 'App\Http\Controllers\PublicPollsController');
Route::resource('admin/public_polls.public_poll_options', 'App\Http\Controllers\PublicPollsOptionsController',array('except' => array('index')));

/** Define filter to all admin actions **/
Route::when('admin/*', 'isAdmin');


/** Login/Register Routes **/
Route::get('/', array(
  'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\loginController@index',
  'as' => 'home'
));

Route::post('/', array(
  'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\loginController@login',
  'as' => 'home'
));

Route::post('register', array(
  'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\loginController@register',
  'as' => 'register'
));

Route::get('register', array(
  'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\loginController@index',
  'as' => 'register'
));

/*Route::get('logout', array(
  'uses' => 'loginController@logout',
  'as' => 'logout'
))->before('auth');
*/

Route::get('welcome', function() {


  if ( User::isAdmin(Auth::user()->id) ) {
    return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
  }

  return View::make('welcome');

});



/*
Route::get('teste', function() {
  return 'Ecrã de teste';
  dd(User::isAdmin(Auth::user()->id));
});*/



/** Email Routes **/
Route::get('email', function() {

    $data['name'] = 'Random_Name';

    // Mail::pretend();
    Mail::send('emails.auth.accountActivation', $data, function($message){
        $message->to('random_email@email.com')->subject('Welcome');
    });

    return 'Email sent!';
});


/*
Event::Listen('laravel.query', function(){
    var_dump($sql);
});*/
```

Comment: I presume you're trying to run middleware on all `admin/` routes? If so, take a look at `Route::middleware`; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware

Comment: Apparently `isAdmin` is a filter https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters. You'd want to find the implementation (most likely a separate class) & convert it to a route middleware as explained in the link in the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind fellows, found the solution, it was as easy as doing a Route::group() and moving the resources with /admin inside the group.

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => '/admin',
  'as' => 'admin.',
], function () {
  Route::resource('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', array('only' => array('index')));
  Route::resource('/companies', 'App\Http\Controllers\CompaniesController');
  Route::resource('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController');
  
  Route::resource('/public_polls', 'App\Http\Controllers\PublicPollsController');
  Route::resource('/public_polls.public_poll_options', 'App\Http\Controllers\PublicPollsOptionsController',array('except' => array('index')));
  
});


/** Define filter to all admin actions **/
//Route::when('admin/*', 'isAdmin');
```

This way it also generates the stuff like admin.companies.create and admin.users.create